# Using Group By When Insert Into Variables

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to select values from a table into a set of variables.  I need to use the `SUM` function to find the totals of one of the values.  Here is the coding I have so far:

```
select sum(sales)
  into pv_totals
  from sales_table
    where id = 23
      group by sales;
```

However, this doesn't seem to work properly.  How do I use a `group by` clause with an `insert into` statement?

Comment: We need the table creation scripts (or at least the subset you reference) for both tables, and sample starting/result data.  Your biggest problem is probably your chosen grouping criteria.

Comment: If that sales value is just one value on one row there is no need for the sum function nor the group by clause. In any event, that query doesn't make sense because you are grouping by the very field you're summing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I can try to explain where you are going wrong. 
If you are using below code, it simply means summation of all the values of SALES column and put it into pv_totals.

`select sum(sales) into pv_totals from sales_table;`

If you are using below code, it says that "As mentioned above" + "for the row with id = 23", it does not make sense.

`select sum(sales) into pv_totals from sales_table where id = 23;`

Coming to Group by, you should use it with other column such as

`select dept,sum(marks) from table_name where group by dept;`

which says list all the totals marks of each department eg:

computer   40
phsycis     70 etc...

Comment: Actually, the second one _does_ make sense, if there's more than one row with `id = 23` (say, if it's `customer_id` or something - then it's "total up all sales for a given customer").  He should be grouping by something other than `sales`, as you point out, because he's going to be getting some strange results otherwise...

Comment: yes ..basically I felt the whole query ambiguous... did not understand the requirement